# Math programming with python

Tags: python

So I'm pretty new to programming and I don't understand how to do this problem. 
Egg cartons each hold exactly 12 eggs. Write a program which reads an integer number of eggs from input(), then prints out two numbers: how many cartons can be filled by these eggs, and how many eggs will be left over. I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Sounds like homework...

Comment: Is this homework? If so, read over [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), especially "Questions asking for homework help".

Comment: *cough* [`divmod`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/divmod) *cough*

Comment: Try editing this by adding what you've done so far. this is required in homework related questions :)

Comment: Look up the integer division operations: % and divmod are your best friends.  If you expect more detailed help, you have to provide more detailed work.  Write some code that at least reads input and *tries* to compute an answer.  If you get stuck, post your code and output here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows zero effort.

Answer (score 1):

At first, what you are looking for is the modulo operator and the function math.floor()

## Modulo

from wikipedia:

> In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another (sometimes called modulus).

for example:

```
12%12=0
24%12=0
25%12=1
```

this does fit your needs for the eggs that are leftover.

## Math.floor()

returns the largest following integer.

eg.:

```
Math.floor(13/2)
```

would be the same as

```
Math.floor(6.5)
```

and result in 6.

This function should solve your problem with the fully filled egg cartons.

### Hint

remember to import floor() properly.

```
from math import floor
```

---

### First, try to figure the rest out on your own.

You shouldn't look at this until your code is done.
Either way I'm not your mom, if you wanna die dumb I tried to prevent it.

https://github.com/AiyionPrime/EggCartons

---

One last thing.
It does not matter wether your attempts to solve a problem were stupid or failed hard.
But if you ever expect an answer to one of your problems you should explain what you tried.
We're not here to solve your problems, but to help you understand to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that text. It comes from a site for exercising with Python coding.
Its name is Computer Science Circles, if I remember correctly.

Anyway, the correct answer at that specific exercise is:

```
eggs = input()     #Reads imput, assigning it to the "eggs" variable
eggs = int(eggs)   #Converts the "eggs" variable into an int

print(eggs // 12)  #Performs a division, showing the result and ignoring the  remainder, giving you the exact number of cartons that can be filled by the "eggs" variable
print(eggs % 12)   #Performs a second division, this time showing only the remainder, giving you the exact number of eggs that will be left over
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.